# Почему optimistic locking так назвали?

Tags: терминология, concurrency, любой-язык

Почему, например, в java *optimistic lock* называется именно так, а не иначе?

Comment: Сам предмет блокировок по-сути не связан с конкретным яп.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

В случае использования *оптимистической* блокировки ([optimistic lock](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/optimisticOfflineLock.html)) вы **сначала** пытаетесь выполнить действия, а уже потом смотрите не приводит ли результат к несогласованности данных (конфликту изменений, и т.д.). Само название происходит из факта, что при оптимистической блокировке вероятность возникновения конфликта предполагается малой и вы производите действия что называется "*на удачу*" (в надежде на то, что конфликта не будет).

В противовес, при использовании *пессимистической* блокировки ([pessimistic lock](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/pessimisticOfflineLock.html)) вы полностью блокируете ресурс, а уже **потом** производите над ним действия. В этом случае, вы *очень сомневаетесь* в том, что ваши действия закончатся без возникновения конфликта.

Comment: если посмотреть на реализацию в Java, например, то вы не будете "смотреть не приводит ли результат к несогалсованности данных". Там оптимистическая блокировка ставится на read-методы, при этом читать могут многие, а изменять - нет. И наоборот - когда кто-то вызывает read-метод, другие действия делать уже нельзя. И потоки вынуждены ждать.

Comment: Если поток вынужден ждать после того, как кто-то прочитал данные -- то это пессимистическая блокировка. Ну и потом я говорю скорее не о реализациях, а о паттернах проектирования: [оптимистическая блокировка](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/optimisticOfflineLock.html), [пессимистическая блокировка](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/pessimisticOfflineLock.html).

Comment: ну как видим, реализация этого паттерна в джава не совпадает с вашим описанием. Поток , который пишет вынужден джать, а который читает - нет. Разве это пессимистическая ?!

Comment: Да, это пессимистическая блокировка. А описание изначально не мое, а Мартина Фаулера (см. ссылки). =) Я скорее поверю, что что-то не так с вашей реализацией (или с вашей ее трактовкой), чем с терминологией по блокировкам.